# Error deploying to SQL Azure using EF 6 alpha3 Code First and Migrations creating __MigrationHistory table

Tags: entity-framework, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF 6 alpha 3 code first.
When I try to create the database on SQL Azure running the Update-Database command I get the following error:

Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server. Please create a clustered index and try again.

I tracked down the error to the __MigrationHistory table creation sql command.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] (
    [MigrationId] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [ContextKey] [nvarchar](512) NOT NULL,
    [Model] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL,
    [ProductVersion] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.__MigrationHistory] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([MigrationId], [ContextKey])
)
```

Anyone has any idea about how can I workaround this problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a [bug](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/936) in Alpha 3 - Sorry for the inconvenience.

There is a pretty easy workaround:

1) Create a custom migration SQL generator:

```
public class AzureSqlGenerator : SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator
{
    protected override void Generate(CreateTableOperation createTableOperation)
    {
        if ((createTableOperation.PrimaryKey != null)
            && !createTableOperation.PrimaryKey.IsClustered)
        {
            createTableOperation.PrimaryKey.IsClustered = true;
        }

        base.Generate(createTableOperation);
    }
}
```

2) Register the custom generator in your migrations configuration:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyContext> 
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;

        SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new AzureSqlGenerator());
    }

    protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to be fixed in latest bits. Thanks!!

Comment: Have it been fixed in the nuget package (alpha 3) ?

Comment: Still have the problem from the nuget package.  Also, if you already have the __MigrationHistory table before upgrading, this won't work until you delete the table.  I deleted the Migrations folder in my project and ran Enable-Migrations again and then added the SetSqlGenerator call and it worked.

Comment: This seems to be resolved in 6.0.0-beta1, as I had the problem, then updated (to 6.0.0-beta1), and everything was ok.

Comment: Good catch on the _MigrationHistory table Tom!

Comment: I'm using EF 6.1.3 and this bug still exists. The above code fixed it though.