# Model First approach in Entity Framework does not create clustered index on SQL Azure

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, azure-sql-database

I try to do an insert in to n:n (SQL Azure based) related tables ('UserSet' and 'TenantSet') using the Entity Framework, but it fails with the error: “tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of sql server”.

I’ve used the model first approach to generate the SQL database, and I see that in the SQL-script that the table 'UserTenant' that is used to store the n:n relationship creates a NONCLUSTERED index that is causing the issues.

Of course I can manually correct this problem by modifying the script (as described [here](http://www.cloud-developer.eu/blog/2013/03/24/tables-without-a-clustered-index-are-not-supported-in-this-version-of-sql-server/), but as soon as I regenerate the database, this correction is lost.

Has anyone any idea how to correct this issue permanently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a bug with Entity Framework and Azure.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248037/error-deploying-to-sql-azure-using-ef-6-alpha3-code-first-and-migrations-creatin/15282861#15282861) StackOverflow-answer to see a workaround.

Basically you have to:

**1) Create a custom migration SQL generator**

**2) Register the custom generator in your migrations configuration**