# Entity Framework Identity - Duplicate UserId in UserLogin

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity, user-roles

I'm extending all the Identity tables. Every thing is working well, but in the database UserLogin gets an extra column named User_Id.

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User");
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>().ToTable("UserRole");
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin");
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().ToTable("Role");

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserLogin>().HasKey<int>(ul => ul.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().HasKey<int>(r => r.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>().HasKey(ur => new { ur.RoleId, ur.UserId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>()
            .HasRequired(ur => ur.User)
            .WithMany(u => u.UserRoles)
            .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);


public class UserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int>
{
}
```

The UserLogin table looks like this:
UserId | LoginProvider | ProviderKey | User_Id

I suspect that it have something to do with HasKey. If I remove that row I get an error saying that UserLogin needs an id, but I can then add public int Id... to the UserLogin class. The table will then look like this:
Id | UserId | LoginProvider | ProviderKey

Does any one have a clue where this extra user id is coming from and how I can get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked this ages ago, but I have just seen it.
Just incase you never answered it, you need to change your UserLogin.HasKey to this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserLogin>().HasKey(m => new { m.UserId, m.ProviderKey });
```

If you just have the **UserId** as the primary key, then you are suggesting a one to one relationship (because the **UserId** has to be unique) which is not right.
Once you have changed to include the provider key, then you can do this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(m => m.Logins).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(m => m.UserId);
```

And then you will have your table set up correctly.

Comment: It worked localy, but I got problems with the migrations when I published to Azure :-(
I got this error "Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server". Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: What version of EF are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 6.1.2

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248037/error-deploying-to-sql-azure-using-ef-6-alpha3-code-first-and-migrations-creatin and let me know if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the migration to this:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropTable("dbo.UserLogin");
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.UserLogin",
            c => new
            {
                LoginProvider = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                ProviderKey = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                UserId = c.Int(nullable: false),
            })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.LoginProvider, t.ProviderKey, t.UserId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.User", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.UserId);
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropTable("dbo.UserLogin");
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.UserLogin",
            c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                LoginProvider = c.String(),
                ProviderKey = c.String(),
                UserId = c.Int(nullable: false),
            })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.User", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.UserId);
    }
```